# PHP Block Text Matching length, start character nd end character?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm converting PDF to TXT and have an issue with line breaks on certain criteria, i.e. Membership numbers. I want to **insert** a line break, `<br />`, before the membership numbers.

The membership number is 7 alphanumeric chars long, starting with a `0` and ending with a character, A-Z, e.g. `069065A`.

`/^[0]|[0-9]{5}|[A-Z]$/gm` - Matches first and last characters, and 5 digits.

How can I use preg_replace to pre-pend a line break and not alter the membership number?

UPDATED:

```
$pattern = '/^[0]|[0-9]{5}|[A-Z]$/gm';
$replacement = '<br />$0';
// execute function
$PDFContent = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

Not working and no error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are matching a contiguous sequence for what are the [vertical bars](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)? Remove those and set margins depending on your data if not already. Your current [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` *start* and `$` *end* together with the `m` *multiline* [flag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) are fine to match from line-start to line-end. If this membership id occurs somewhere in a larger text, use e.g. [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` or whitespace [`(?<!\S)`...`(?!\S)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead.

```
^0[A-Z\d]{5}[A-Z]$
```

See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/29yTQs/1) or a [PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##jY7Ba4MwHIXv@St@EyEK1XhpodROetuxsFuXbiQ1akCTkER6GP3bnWHdRVrY7b13eN9nOjNNZXV8OyJECDRWD9BLJTLnmfXg9W8TqobkKn0Hw9h7GTZoetamKHbewh6iYrMtNusDVcsQ7ZC4dBqMFe2XFaZnF5Fg8ll8HLITrc/f61tI55gMeAW45BbIa1zMOVynkENE1XwS9EYnVQtXbWvgelQ1s1K4PwXcaJ3doXmec2bxYzTlSzbl5L/sTnrhzHz0xADuBk/YSVW@0Pd0KZBUYX0osUPT9AM) (replacement with `<br />$0` is fine).

*Note*: You can drop the `g` flag, it does not exist in PHP. [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) will always do a *global* replacement as far as no `$limit` is set. The `m` flag is needed for `^` *start* and `$` *end* [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). If you're using e.g. word boundaries `\b` instead and dropping those, you can drop the `m` flag too.